# Can not log out correctly PHP

Tags: php, logout

I can log in and access all member pages, but when I log out, I can still access all memberspages

I use this code to log out:

```
$_SESSION["admin_id"] = false;
$_SESSION["username"] = null;
redirect_to("login.php");
```

and this code to check if a user is logged in,

```
function logged_in() {
    return isset($_SESSION["admin_id"]);
}

function confirm_logged_in($page) {
    if (!logged_in()) {
        redirect_to($page);
    }
}
```

he redirects me after i have used the log out code. But i can still type in the member page URL and access them like I am logged in. I use an other webbrowser its impossible, so the pages are protected correctly. Or do I need to destroy the cookie and session complectly?

Comment: and `redirect_to()` contains/does what? are you unsetting/destroying the session and has the session been started inside all pages using sessions?

Comment: When the variable has value `false`, it still exists and `isset()` returns `true`.

Comment: redirect_to is just fucntion to redirect, but i putted in a function to make it shorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're doing when you logout.

You are **setting** `admin_id` to `false` (which is technically a value).

```
$_SESSION["admin_id"] = false;
```

You then check to see whether `admin_id` is **set:**

```
isset($_SESSION['admin_id');  // returns TRUE because it "IS SET" to false
```

**Options**

You can either check whether `admin_id` is not empty (which handles `null`, `false`, `0`).

```
function logged_in() {
    return ! empty($_SESSION["admin_id"]);
}
```

You can extend your current function.

```
function logged_in() {
    return isset($_SESSION["admin_id"] && $_SESSION["admin_id"] !== false);
}
```

You can set the variable to null.

```
$_SESSION['admin_id'] = null;
```

You can destroy the session completely.

```
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of:

```
$_SESSION["admin_id"] = false;
```

Try this:

```
unset($_SESSION["admin_id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to log out, in my opinion your best option is to invalidate the session with a simple **session_destroy()**.
By doing this you can check $_SESSION with the isset() function without problems, since every parameter belonging to the old session has been unset.